# Facebook omniauth using AES_128_GCM encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssl, heroku

I have built an app in Rails and hooked up SSL through expedited SSL and Heroku.  I implemented Facebook omniauth for users to log on as well.  When using the standard log in method the connection is indeed secure with a green lock showing in chromes browser window.  When users log on via Facebook omniauth though, the have a lock with a caution symbol, and the explanation of:

```
The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and uses ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
```

Since I am just learning, I do not know if I should be concerned about this or not.  My gut says to not worry about it, but it still makes me feel uneasy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I was using http: instead of https: inside of a model when grabbing user images.  Simple oversight.